# How can I generate pages in Assemble based on an different json files?

Tags: assemble

So I have a folder `rules` that that looks like this:

```
rule-001.json
rule-002.json
rule-003.json
```

Each *.json file is of a unified format:

```
{ name: 'AAA', descriptions: 'BBB' }
```

How can I generate a pages based on these files in Assemble?

Comment: Do you need 1 output file for each input JSON file?  It is relatively easy to [add custom data from JSON files](http://assemble.io/docs/Data.html) to the global data set, but harder to dynamically generate output files utilizing the data from an arbitrary set of JSON input files.

Comment: I wish I could generate 1. Multiple files with full detaild; 2. One single file with the list of names.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you need to load your JSON data in your Gruntfile and use it to replace the Assemble `pages` object.

I have written a [blog post about generating pages from data](http://opsbynumbers.com/2014/11/06/learning-assemble-step-10-pages-from-data/), based on the [Assemble Blog Theme sample](https://github.com/upstage/assemble-blog-theme).  In both cases, the pages data was stored in a single JSON file.

In your case, you need to load the data from all of JSON files in your Gruntfile, and transform the data into the `pages` format.  You can do this any number of ways, but one simple way would be to write a function in your Gruntfile that does this:

```
function loadDataPages (jsonFileSpec) {
    var path = require("path");
    var jsonPaths = grunt.file.expand(jsonFileSpec);
    var jsonPages = jsonPaths.map(function (jsonPath) {
        var jsonData = grunt.file.readJSON(jsonPath);
        var outputFileName = path.basename(jsonPath, path.extname(jsonPath)) + ".html";
        var jsonPage = {
            "data": jsonData,
            "content": "This is the body content for page " + outputFileName,
            "filename": outputFileName
        };
        return jsonPage;
    });
    return jsonPages;
}
```

and then you need to load this data object in your Grunt config and pass it to Assemble's `pages` option:

```
grunt.initConfig({
    assemble: {
        data: {
            options: {
                flatten: true,
                layout: "source/templates/layouts/custom-data-layout.hbs",
                pages: loadDataPages("source/custom-data/*.json")
            },
            files: {
                "output/custom-data-pages/": ["source/custom-data/index.hbs"]
            }
        }
    }
    // ...
});
```

Here is what the layouts might look like:

**custom-data-layout.hbs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Custom Data - {{name}}</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Custom Data - {{name}}</h1>
        <p>{{ description }}</p>
        {{> body }}
    </body>
</html>
```

**index.hbs**

```
---
layout: false
title: Custom Data Index
---
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>{{title}}</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>{{title}}</h1>
<ul>
    {{#each pages }}
        <li><a href="{{relativeLink}}">{{basename}}</a></li>
    {{/each}}
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you. You just create separate Assemble tasks and call the main Assemble task with grunt.

https://gist.github.com/davidwickman/a0bf961e3099ea6b9c35